# How to write COM object for text service framework?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2011, how do I write a COM object for text service framework?

Comment: It's explained in the *MSDN Library* titled *[Text Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms629031(v=vs.85).aspx)*.